# GWT: how do I go to a new place from within the Activity start method?

Tags: java, gwt

So I'm doing something like this:

```
public class SecureActivity extends AbstractActivity {
  public void start(AcceptsOneWidget container, EventBus eventBus) {    
    if (!_app.isUserLoggedIn()) {
      _app.goTo(new LoginPlace(_app.getCurrentPlaceToken()))
    } else {
      // do cool secure stuff
    }
  }
}
```

But the behavior that I'm seeing is that my browser's history is for original url (from the original request), then the login:redirectPlace, and then original url again.

It seems like I need to do my redirection after the start() method has completed. Is there a proper way to delay/delegate that goTo to happen outside of the start method?

Thanks.

Comment: Thomas' answer is one way to get around this. You may want to think about how your places are mapped to activities a little though, because if you have your activity immediately redirect to a new place when it starts you put a token in the user's history that won't make sense to them. Instead, you could pull your if (!_app.isUserLoggedIn()) conditional into your ActivityMapper, and start the LoginActivity instead of starting the SecureActivity and then changing places to get to the LoginActivity. (i.e. you don't always have to have a 1-to-1 mapping of places to activities).

Comment: Ben, that's an excellent suggestion. I have been thinking along the lines of a 1-to-1 mapping. In particular, I've been setting the SecureActivity to play the role of testing authorization. If I move that to the mapper, once a log-in is successful, do I use places to retry going to the original place? Or do I manually invoke calls to my mapper to get that activity started?

Comment: That's a good question! What I forgot about is that you cannot goTo() a place that you are already at, so you're right, you would have to manually start the new activity (which doesn't quite seem right). This probably deserves its own question; maybe the GWT team would chime in on what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be enough:

```java
Scheduler.get().scheduleFinally(new ScheduledCommand() {
   @Override
   public void execute() {
      _app.goTo(new LoginPlace(_app.getCurrentPlaceToken());
   }
}
```