# How to handle invalid GWT token in places

Tags: gwt, gwt-activities, gwt-places

In Contacts project, if a user entered an invalid token for contact editing, how to should handle it, for example, instead of `#contactId:12` , entered `#contactId:abc`. Or in another app, maybe for security reason (such as authorization), the user does not have required permission for editing an object, how to inform user. I tried to navigate to a place such as `InvalidUrlPlace` but can not.
I can not navigate from inside of `Activity.start()`  method , using `placeController.goTo()`

update1:

```
@Override
public void start(AcceptsOneWidget containerWidget, EventBus eventBus)
{
    GWT.log("inside start() method");
    if (assertValidPlace())
    {
        containerWidget.setWidget(view);
        initialize();
    }
}

protected boolean assertValidPlace()
{
    if (!place.isValid())
    {
                GWT.log("going to InvalidUrlPlace");
                placeController.goTo(new InvalidUrlPlace());
                return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

update2:

```
<code>
public class InvalidUrlPlace extends Place
{
    private Messages messages = GWT.create(Messages.class);
    private InvalidToken invalidToken;

    public InvalidUrlPlace()
    {
    }

    public InvalidUrlPlace(InvalidToken invalidToken)
    {
        this.invalidToken = invalidToken;
    }

    public InvalidToken getInvalidToken()
    {
        return invalidToken;
    }

    public String getMessage()
    {
        if (invalidToken != null)
            return invalidToken.getMessage();
        return messages.pageNotFound();
    }

    @Prefix("invalidUrl")
    public static class Tokenizer implements PlaceTokenizer<InvalidUrlPlace>
    {
        @Override
        public InvalidUrlPlace getPlace(String token)
        {
            return new InvalidUrlPlace();
        }

        @Override
        public String getToken(InvalidUrlPlace place)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can navigate anywhere you like from Activity.start() using placeController.goTo(). Show your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I updated the message

Comment: **Solved** The problem answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003229/gwt-how-do-i-go-to-a-new-place-from-within-the-activity-start-method#answers-header)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void start(AcceptsOneWidget containerWidget, EventBus eventBus)
{
    if (place.isValid())
    {
        containerWidget.setWidget(view);
        initialize();
    }
    else
    {
        placeController.goTo(new InvalidUrlPlace());
    }
}
```

You are trying to execute code (`return false`) after you already told the activity to leave to a new place - i.e. finish this activity and start a new one.

Comment: thanks, this code worked, but the url (token) not updated to InvalidUrlPlace token, and still has the old token.

Comment: Do you get any errors? It should be InvalidUrlPlace(""), by the way, unless you added a new constructor to `Place`.

Comment: I use InvalidUrlPlace as a regular place, and it worked totally, but if navigate from start() method, this problem raise, also from the current activity, cannot navigate to the same activity with an other token

Comment: InvalidUrlPlace has two constructor, if i use default constructor, the result not changed, i update message and add the InvalidUrlPlace code, also if i use OtherPlace that work fine, instead of InvalidUrlPlace, i can not navigate that from inside of start() method correctly and the url does not update, thanks again

Comment: Place does not have a no-args constructor. You probably should do: `public InvalidUrlPlace() {super("");}  Same with the other constructor that you use.

Comment: com.google.gwt.place.shared.Place does not have any constructor

Comment: My bad - it's an abstract class. Do you see any errors (e.g. exceptions) in your browser tools?

Comment: No, I use IntelliJ IDEA and chrome developer tools, I dont know what exactly is wrong here?